# For Loop Not Repeating

Tags: math

I'm trying to find the hrefs for all the states where this company has stores, however it only finds the href for the first state.

Can anyone figure out why the for loop doesn't repeat for the rest of the states? Thank you very much for your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# website
sitemap = 'website_url'
# content of website
sitemap_content = requests.get(sitemap).content
# parsing website
soup = BeautifulSoup(sitemap_content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
list_of_divs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'listings-inner'})
#print(list_of_divs)

header = ['Links']
with open ('/Users/ABC/Desktop/v1.csv','wt') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter ="\t" )
    writer.writerow(header)

    for state in list_of_divs:
        # get the url's by state
        print(state.find('div', attrs={'class':'itemlist'}).a.get('href'))

        rows = [state.find('div', attrs={'class':'itemlist'}).a.get('href')]

        writer.writerow(rows)
```

Comment: There's only one `<div class="listings-inner">`. What are you specting the loop to loop over?

Comment: The states are in `<a class="ga_w2gi_lp">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list_of_divs` actually only contains one element, which is the only div on the page with class `listings-inner`. So when you iterate through all of it's elements and use the [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method, it'll only return the first result.

You want to use the [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method on that div:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sitemap = 'https://stores.dollargeneral.com/'
sitemap_content = requests.get(sitemap).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(sitemap_content, 'html.parser')

listings_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'listings-inner'})

for state in listings_div.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'itemlist'}):
    print(state.a.get('href'))
```